# No Suitable User Defined Conversion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, syntax-error

Inside 'CompaniesMap.h':

```
class CompaniesMap
{
public:
...
    // The companies map
    map<string, CompanyP> companies;
};

typedef map<string, CompanyP>::iterator map_it;
```

In 'CompaniesMap.cpp':

```
string* CompaniesMap::displayCompaniesList() const
{
    string* compList = new string[companies.size() + 1];        // We add 1 so we can start with the [1] index for simplicity

    // Check if 'companies' is empty
    if (companies.empty())
    {
        cout << "No companies in the database." << endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

    for (map_it it = companies.begin(), int i = 1; it != companies.end(); ++it, i++)
    {
        cout << "   " << i << ") " << it->first << endl;
        compList[i] = it->first;
    }
}
```

Visual Studio shows a red line under `companies.begin()` with the following error message:
[image]

I've tried changing the code from `map_it it =` to `map<string, CompanyP>::iterator` But I still get this error

I had the same code in `main.cpp` but decided to move it to a seperate class, I include the same relevant headers and still see this error. When I try to build I get different errors from this file:

```
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(66): error C2062: type 'int' unexpected
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(66): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(66): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(67): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(68): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\asaf\c\vs\hw5\hw5\hw5\companiesmap.cpp(69): error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
```

Comment: With this "We add 1 so we can start with the [1] index for simplicity
" you fool everyone used to program C/C++. (I doubt it's simplicity)

Comment: Not exactly sure, but... `CompaniesMap::displayCompaniesList()` is `const`, which means all class members are effectively `const` in the function, which means iterating `companies` requires `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`.

Comment: @DieterLücking
The menu shows the list of the company with  "1)","2)",etc... prefixes. Isn't it more simpler that the companies are associated with their menu number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayCompaniesList` is a `const` function, meaning that you can't make any change to the variables defined in the class.

`companies` will thus be a `const std::map<std::string, CompanyP>`, and not a `std::map<std::string, CompanyP>`, and so you have to change your iterator accordingly:

```
std::map<std::string, CompanyP>::const_iterator it = companies.begin();

//Or even better if you use C++11
auto it = companies.begin();
```

Comment: I changed the code to `typedef map<const string, CompanyP>::iterator map_it;` and still get the same problem

Comment: And when trying to use `auto` I get the `cannot deduce auto type` error

Comment: added the following `typedef map<string,const CompanyP>::iterator map_const_it;` and changed `it` to: `map_const_it it = companies.begin()`.
Still get the error.